# Android color indentification

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop an app that uses android camera to divide screen into 64 blocks and then analyze the percentage of colors present in each block seperaely. Any source codes or any links to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful:

http://aerilys.fr/blog/?p=1341

Or you can inspired by this:

http://www.spyontech.com/apps/android/detect-photos-object-colors-in-android-by-color-grab.htm